# Passing Psobject Property values to another Psobject

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using two PSObjects lets call them $job1 and $job2 that contain some identical Property Names.  The properties for  $job1 has the values but the matching properties for $job2 does not.I need to be able to do a  foreach loop where if property name in $job1 matches $job2 property name, update Property value of $job2 based on the Property Name.

I was playing around with the below code but I cannot get it to update the Property values of $job2.

```
$job1.PSObject.Properties | %{if($_.Name -in $job2.PSObject.Properties.Name){[$_.Value = $job2.PSObject.Properties.Value}}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Foreach ( $Property in $Job1.Psobject.Properties.Name )
{
 Try { $Job2.$Property = $Job1.$Property }
 Catch { Continue }
}
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you, never tried the try and catch statement in powershell.